# Remove iPhone detection on Wordpress login page

Tags: php, iphone, wordpress, mobile, mobile-safari

I have wordpress a site with a customized login page, the problem is when I go to that page on my iPhone, it detects it as an iPhone and adds the viewport meta tag, which normally would be great but this particular login page I want to be viewed full sized and zoomable, not iPhone sized and non-zoomable. So I need to remove the iPhone detection from the login page without modifying the wordpress core. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Add this to the functions file:

```
function remove_iphone_detection() {
    global $is_iphone;
    $is_iphone = false;
}

add_action('init', 'remove_iphone_detection');
```

Though this removes iphone detection from wordpress a a whole, not just the login page, it achieved what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try asking this question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or http://wordpress.org/.